# CRT-based S3 Client (S3AsyncClient) throws Error 1067 AWS_IO_TLS_NEGOTIATION_TIMEOUT

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-s3-client

I have a basic S3Client that works perfectly fine and when I use a S3AsyncClient to do any S3 operation - I get Error 1067 AWS_IO_TLS_NEGOTIATION_TIMEOUT. Followed the steps in this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-crt-based-s3-client-and-the-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/) to set up the S3AsyncClient - it uses a CRT-based S3 client.

This is using AWS SDK v2

Any inputs?

I tried including the required crt http client and also enabled debug logs using sdk v2 log4j configuration, but no luck .